# How to remove data from $data Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, forms, validation

I'm using the validator of laravel to create a login validation and I've got 2 types of users with my login. One with a value PAR (client) and one with PRO (professional). If the radio button pro is checked it add 3 more fields to my form.
How can I do to remove those fields from `$data` when I'm a client ?
Here is what I tested :

```
// VERIFICATION OF THE USER'S STATUS
    if($data['status'] == 'PAR') {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            // CLIENT PART
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'surname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email_user' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'gender' => 'required|string',
            'birth' => 'required|date',
            'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'pc' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:4,5',
            'status' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
    }

    else if($data['status'] == 'PRO') {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            // PROFESSIONNAL PART
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'surname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email_user' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'gender' => 'required|string',
            'birth' => 'required|date',
            'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'pc' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:4,5',
            'status' => 'required|string|max:255',

            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'license' => 'requiredmimes:jpeg,pdf,png',
            'urssaf' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,pdf,png'
        ]);
    }
```

Then I'll do the same for the User::create function.
I'm using JS to display or not the phone/license/urssaf fields. So in my form, They're already include and send as '' in the form.

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have there? Does it work? Have you looked here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation you'd find this:

> #### required_if:*anotherfield*,*value*,...
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the *anotherfield* field is equal to any *value*.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-if

---

```
    return Validator::make($data, [
        // PROFESSIONNAL PART
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'surname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email_user' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'gender' => 'required|string',
        'birth' => 'required|date',
        'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'city' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'pc' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:4,5',
        'status' => 'required|string|max:255',

        'phone' => 'required_if:status,pro|numeric',
        'license' => 'required_if:status,pro|mimes:jpeg,pdf,png',
        'urssaf' => 'required_if:status,pro|mimes:jpeg,pdf,png'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (`array_except` helper function)[https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-except] from laravel to remove it inside some `if` clause:

```
$data = array_except($data, ['phone', 'license', 'urssaf']);
```

But actually looks like you need to remove items from your validation rules, not from the data.

Since your rules are almost the same for both situations, you can do something like this:

```
$rules = [ 
    /** Common rules here */
]

if ($data['status'] == 'PRO') {
    $rules = array_merge($rules, [
    /** Specific rules here */
    ]
}

return Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

This will avoid you need to repeat yourself.

You can also use the first piece of code if you also want to remove the fields from $data in order to avoid bad-intentioned user filling that fields.